# VHDL 10500 : error syntax near text

Tags: syntax, vhdl, quartus

I have this vhdl code :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity avalon_fir_4 is
port (
    clk, reset: in std_logic;
    -- avalon interface
    gcd_address: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); -- 3-bit address
    gcd_chipselect: in std_logic;
    gcd_write: in std_logic;
    gcd_writedata: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    gcd_readdata: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end avalon_fir_4;

architecture arch of avalon_fir_4 is
signal i_coeff_0    : std_logic_vector( 31 downto 0);
signal i_coeff_1    : std_logic_vector( 31 downto 0);
signal i_coeff_2    : std_logic_vector( 31 downto 0);
signal i_coeff_3    : std_logic_vector( 31 downto 0);
-- data input
signal i_data       : std_logic_vector( 31 downto 0);
-- filtered data 
signal o_data       : std_logic_vector( 31 downto 0);

signal wr_en, wr_a, wr_b, wr_c, wr_d, wr_e: std_logic;
type state_type is (idle, count);
signal state_reg, state_next: state_type;
signal c_reg, c_next: unsigned(15 downto 0);

begin
fir_unit: fir_filter_4 port map(clk, reset, i_coeff_0, i_coeff_1, i_coeff_2, i_coeff_3, i_data, o_data);

process (clk, reset)
begin
--if reset=’1’ then
        --o_data  <= (others=>(others=>'0'));
        --data  <= (others=>(others=>'0'));
        --i_coeff_0 <= (others=>(others=>'0'));
        --i_coeff_1 <= (others=>(others=>'0'));
        --i_coeff_2 <= (others=>(others=>'0'));
        --i_coeff_3 <= (others=>(others=>'0'));
--elsif (clk'event and clk=’1’) then
    if wr_a=’1’ then
        i_data <= gcd_writedata;
    elsif wr_b=’1’ then
        i_coeff_0 <= gcd_writedata;
    elsif wr_c='1' then
        i_coeff_1 <= gcd_writedata;
    elsif wr_d='1' then
        i_coeff_2 <= gcd_writedata;
    elsif wr_e='1' then
        i_coeff_3 <= gcd_writedata;
    end if;
--end if;
end process;

wr_en <=’1’ when gcd_write=’1’ and gcd_chipselect=’1’ else ’0’;
wr_a <= ’1’ when gcd_address="000" and wr_en=’1’ else ’0’;
wr_b <= ’1’ when gcd_address="001" and wr_en=’1’ else ’0’;
wr_c <= ’1’ when gcd_address="010" and wr_en=’1’ else ’0’;
wr_d <= ’1’ when gcd_address="011" and wr_en=’1’ else ’0’;
wr_e <= ’1’ when gcd_address="100" and wr_en=’1’ else ’0’;
gcd_start <= ’1’ when gcd_address="010" and wr_en=’1’ else ’0’;
gcd_readdata <= r_out when gcd_address="100" else gcd_ready & "000" & x"000" & std_logic_vector(c_reg);
```

end arch;

compilation crash :
[image: crash report]

I have tried many ways of writing the vhdl at multiple places without success. What is this error?

Comment: The crash report says it all; start using the ' instead of ’ in quoting, and then address the next issue in the report.  Creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), will indeed reveal the problem.

Comment: In addition to Morten noting most if not all the character literal '1' s are using illegal characters, some '0' s do too.  There's also no component declaration for fir_filter_4 and no declarations for gcd_start, r_out and gcd_ready.

Comment: Sometimes it's worth trying a diffeernt tool to get a different compilation error message. GHDL for example reports: "ghdl -a avalon_fir_4.vhd 
avalon_fir_4.vhd:36:13: invalid character, even in a comment" which is a bit more useful! From https://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/?source=directory